# JS: Print dynamic output with a for loop. What´s wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I want to generate some input fields dinamically with jQuery.

I want to work with php later on with the values inserted into the input fields, so I need to assign each input with a different name value (ie. `name="celda1"`, `name="celda2"`, etc).

### This is what I´ve tried (**[jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rosamunda/tRKYt/3/)**):

```
<form name="generar-tabla" action="" method="POST">
How Many? <input type='text' id='cantMeses' name='cantMeses'>     
<input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='Generar tabla'>
</form>
```

### And this is my javascript:

```
var cantMeses = getElementById('cantMeses').value;
var celda = "Mes <input type='text' name='nro"+nro+"'>";
$('#submit').click(generarTabla);

var generarTabla = function() {
    var nro = 1;
    for ($i=0; $i<cantMeses; $i++) { 
    $('#output').append(celda);
    var nro = nro + 1;
    }
}
```

The intended output is to print out as many `Mes <input type='text' name='nroX'>` as typed at the `cantMeses` field.

For now it doesn´t work at all. I mean, when I try this out at jFiddle this is the error I get:

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x37b0610>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x37b0e90>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x37b0610>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x37a2e50>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

And the console says that `Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined` at `fiddle.jshell.net/:21`

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest issue is here:

```
var nro += nro + 1;
```

When I'm pretty sure you either mean

```
nro += 1;
```

or

```
nro = nro + 1;
```

Note:

Both the math was incorrect, *and* you created a local copy of `nro` which hide the outer one.  The local copy was `undefined` each time you entered the loop and `undefined + 1`  results in `NaN` -- Not a Number.

Comment: See my updated comment, I missed a bit.  And `Doesn't work` is the absolute *lease* useful description that can be given. It has to be doing *something*

Comment: Yes, thanks! I´ve updated the question. In there I explain what I do mean with that vague "doesn´t work" :)